# TCP Flags in Python

Tags: security, tcp, flags

I trying to run a code where a server can check the flags in the packets it receives from client. I need to do that as a detection for TCP reset attack. So basically i want the server to be able to check if he is receiving multiple RESET packets.

any help please? i need that in python.

Comment: You will get those via error codes. You don't need to examine packets for this.

Comment: @user207421 what do you mean by error codes?

Comment: Actually no, you will not get it via error codes in case the RST happens right after the first TCP handshake packet. The socket will not be opened, so no error on the application level will be visible.

Comment: I have used scapy a longer while ago and I believe this could address your need, although I don't have an exact solution in my head. Scapy can run in a mode that listens to incoming traffic and allows you to evaluate incoming packets afterwards. Feel free to have a look and play with this lib.

Comment: i am trying to. But thank you @MarekPuchalski